# Can't upload ipa to diawi.com

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, xcode6.4, diawi

I'm creating an ipa using distribution certificate(for Ad-hoc) using `WildCard ID`.

My wildcard ID is `com.company.*` so i set my bundleId to `com.company.test`. ipa successfully generating with this.

It can also install on my device but can not upload it to diawi. It gives me the error:

- No provisioning profile found in the application bundle.
- A technical error occurred

I have 3 Distribution Certificated created in account from 3 different MAC and i also installed all privet key for 3.

I'm using `Xcode 6.4`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps to upload your app at diawi:

1. Archive your application
2. Export the item for adHoc distribution
3. Save the ipa at particular location
4. Upload the same ipa at diawi

Reasons for not getting upload ipa at diawi:

- You may building the application using developer certificates
- You go to product, then create ipa using iTunes
- You are upload the same ipa. 
  Please Archive the build as stated above, and it will upload successfully.

Comment: im creating ipa using this 4 step. im also using distribution certificate.

Comment: Distribution or adhoc? Try with adHoc. Also if still error occurs, try to refresh page.

Comment: Check all targets of your application (including tests), set the correct adhoc provisioning profile. Also set the correct profile for your project's build settings too.

Comment: Revoke the certificate and profile. Re-generate it. Problem solved. This is the solution for worst case scenario 

Comment: 1. Build your application
2. Locate .app
3. zip it
4. Upload the zip file at diawi.

It will upload successfully. It will work with development and adhoc certificates.